# setting cookie in a for loop

Tags: javascript, cookies, for-loop

I am looking since yesterday to fix this problem, I know there are plenty of similar tutorials but somehow they didnt work for my situation.

What I am trying to do is setting the cookie whenever the user click on any product(It should store product_id). So this product is going to be added to chart.

I check it on javascript console of the chrome but there is a strange error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }" and it says there isnt any stored cookie.

```
   echo "<div id='products'>";
    for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++)
        {
            $ftc = mysql_result($result, $i, "product_image");
            $ftc2 = mysql_result($result, $i, "product_id");
            $ftc3 = mysql_result($result, $i, "product_name");
            $ftc4 = mysql_result($result, $i, "product_preis");
            $ftc5 = mysql_result($result, $i, "product_old_preis");
echo "<a href='details.php?product=".$ftc2."'>
<div class='products_list'>
        <img width='217px' height='323px' src='".$ftc."'/>
        <div class='alt_yazi2'><b>".$ftc3 ." &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp 
        <font style='float:right;'>".$ftc4."TL &nbsp;&nbsp<b style='text-decoration:line-through; float:right;'>".$ftc5."TL </b></font></b></a>
    </br>
    <div id='sepet'><a onclick='setCookie('ccname', '".$ftc2."', 'expiry');' href='#'>
    <img width='35px' height='25px' src='images/cart_icon.png'/>
        </a>
        </div>      
    </div></div> ";

        }
        echo "</div> ";

    ?>
```

And this javascript code is on the head of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
// JavaScript Document

var today = new Date();
var expiry = new Date(today.getTime() + 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

function getCookieVal (offset) {
  var endstr = document.cookie.indexOf (";", offset);
  if (endstr == -1) { endstr = document.cookie.length; }
  return unescape(document.cookie.substring(offset, endstr));
  }

function GetCookie (name) {
  var arg = name + "=";
  var alen = arg.length;
  var clen = document.cookie.length;
  var i = 0;
  while (i < clen) {
    var j = i + alen;
    if (document.cookie.substring(i, j) == arg) {
      return getCookieVal (j);
      }
    i = document.cookie.indexOf(" ", i) + 1;
    if (i == 0) break; 
    }
  return null;
  }

function DeleteCookie (name,path,domain) {
  if (GetCookie(name)) {
    document.cookie = name + "=" +
    ((path) ? "; path=" + path : "") +
    ((domain) ? "; domain=" + domain : "") +
    "; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT";
    }
  }

function SetCookie (name,value,expires,path,domain,secure) {
  document.cookie = name + "=" + escape (value) +
    ((expires) ? "; expires=" + expires.toGMTString() : "") +
    ((path) ? "; path=" + path : "") +
    ((domain) ? "; domain=" + domain : "") +
    ((secure) ? "; secure" : "");
  }


</script>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: In any decent browser, it will tell you exactly where it encounters the error (what line number of your code).  That information is usually very helpful.

Comment: Also please change `a onclick='setCookie('ccname', '".$ftc2."', 'expiry');'`  to `a onclick='setCookie('ccname', '".$ftc2."', 'expiry'); return false'`

Comment: also it seems to run on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ufSs3/1/

Comment: I have added return false and the error seems to occur in for loop it says product.php:111 and this red error bubble is between the first and second product sorry I cannot upload the picture because of spam prevention

Comment: and this error occurs after clicking the chart_icon.png which is triggering setCookie

Comment: @user823255 so does it mean that problem occurs on the for loop? I was actually suspicous about parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is probably because of this function `toGMTString()`. If you had used `script type="javascript"`, the `toGMTString()` would have worked. Since you've used `script type="text/javascript"`, you do not need to convert to GMT format, browsers nowadays do it for you.

I suggest you just remove the conversion to GMT and give a try.

Regards

Comment: Yes, I guess, GMTString caused a conflict but it works now thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if your browser is telling you about a javascript error, you should be able to note what line of code it's complaining about and look there for your first error.  Sometimes, the error will point to a line of code after the error rather than the actual line causing the error, but it's usually in the general area of the first error.  So, you should be using that information to help here.

Then, I see these issues:

**Issue #1:** I don't know if this is your first problem or not, but this won't work because of the quoting:

```
<a onclick='setCookie('ccname', '".$ftc2."', 'expiry');' href='#'>
```

You're trying to use single quotes nested inside of single quotes.  That won't work.  I don't know how your template language works so I'm not entirely sure how to fix that part of it, but from HTML/javascript's point of view, you want to use single quotes nested inside of double quotes or vice/versa perhaps like this:

```
<a onclick='setCookie("ccname", ".$ftc2.", "expiry");' href='#'>
```

Comment: I have tried what you said but it gave me sytax error so I have changed it to  <a onclick=\"setCookie('ccname', '".$ftc2."', 'expiry'); return false\" href='#'>  so I have changed first and last single quotes to "\

Comment: and now javascript console says me Uncaught ReferenceError: setCookie is not defined

Comment: That's a good thing.  Now the syntax is correct, but JavaScript is case sensitive.  Change the "onclick" definition to use "SetCookie" instead of "setCookie" and see what happens.

Comment: wow I guess this is a good progress now it says Uncaught TypeError: Object expiry has no method 'toGMTString'

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object expiry has no method 'toGMTString'
SetCookieproduct.php:54
(anonymous function)product.php:110
onclick

Comment: I can not solve it its so strange because expiry brings the current date + 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 and expires handles the toGMTString  " ((expires) ? "; expires=" + expires.toGMTString() : "") +" do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Is the following line in `GetCookie` possibly causing the unexpected syntax issues?

```
if (i == 0) break;
```

All other `if` statements in your code wrap the affected lines in `{` and `}`, but this one does not.  If you change it to `if (i == 0) { break; }`, does that solve your syntax problem?

Comment: unfortunately it didnt change anything